# Is there a library to sign transactions using a cold wallet?

Tags: transactions, signature, private-key, ledger-nano-s, cold-storage

I have a `Ledger Nano S` I want to use for signing transactions on a server. Is it possible to use a library to do this every time without the need of someone manipulating the hardware wallet but ensuring that the keys are still offline at all times?